# Is it possible to navigate SVG object's elements from enclosing HTML?

Tags: svg

I'm loading an SVG through an object tag and need to access SVG's elements (to manipulate them). How can I do that?

Here're partial solutions I'm aware of:

1. Use SVG params where you set params
   for the object tag and parameterize
   attributes of the SVG elements. This
   works great for things like rect, but not for
   g (group) that I need to move (that takes a "transform" that can't be parameterized, looks like).
2. I've seen suggestions to use
   contentDocument or getSVGDocument()
   on the object element that you get
   through getElementById("yoursvgid").
   Unfortunately, neither is
   working - and yes, I'm calling these
   *after* the SVG is loaded.

I can't believe there is no simple/reliable way to access SVG elements from within HTML (searched here/web) - would really appreciate help on this!

Alternatively, if there is some way to call a function defined inside SVG from within HTML (or vice versa), that'd do it too. In general, any way to communicate between SVG and HTML.

Comment: Well... You could use inline SVG instead if object tags...

Comment: To be sure, do you know that you can [embed SVG inside XHTML](http://phrogz.net/svg/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml)?

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to also reach IE8 (which unfortunately I can't ignore...yet). Or is there an inline solution for IE8 too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried different combinations/solutions suggested here/elsewhere, and looks like the best way to handle SVG is to embed the SVG element in the HTML - just make sure you name it as .xhtml. Once you do that, you can simply navigate the DOM and do what you want (like yankee suggested).

I've verified that this works in the current versions of Chrome, FF, Safari, IE, and Opera. It also works in IE8. Below is a rough example that has a button and a gradient bar - if you click on the button, it turns the bar red.

```
<button style="display: block;" onclick="document.getElementById('color').setAttribute('style', 'stop-color:#FF0000');">Color</button>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="49px" height="376px" viewBox="0 0 49 376" enable-background="new 0 0 49 376" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="24" y1="376" x2="24" y2="1.0005">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
        <stop id="color" offset="1" style="stop-color:#000000"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" d="M48,366c0,5.522-4.477,10-10,10H10c-5.523,0-10-4.478-10-10V11C0,5.477,4.477,1,10,1h28
        c5.523,0,10,4.477,10,10V366z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a technique I have used successfully, mentioned in the (very good) O'Reilly "SVG Essentials" book:

1. Add JavaScript code to your SVG document itself and handle the load event on the root svg element.

   ```
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" onload="init(evt)">
   <script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="svgScript.js" />
   ```
2. In this svgScript.js load event handler, write out whatever you need to expose to the HTML-side script through the built-in `parent` variable.

   ```
   function init(evt) {
       svgDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
       parent.theSvgDocument = svgDocument;
   }
   ```
3. Back in your HTML-side script, you can now directly access and use this reference.

   ```
   var svgDocument = theSvgDocument;
   ```

In this example we expose the SVG Document object but you could pass on any object or a function. In my project I actually exposed some kind of controller object reference so that my SVG-side script contains all the logic for manipulating the SVG document, and the HTML-side script merely grabs this controller object and calls public methods on it.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I had tried this (parent in SVG) as well, but the value didn't go through to the HTML (the variable is undefined). Again, this is on Chrome (v9); it worked OK on FF3.6 for example.

Answer (score 0):

If your option 2) doesn't work, I would like to see your example. What browsers are you testing in? Are you using an svg plugin?

Option 2) is one of the things that the [Acid3 test](http://acid3.acidtests.org) checks for (subtest #74).

Comment: Not sure about the Acid3 test thing. I'm getting undefined for both contentDocument and getSVGDocument() on Chrome 9 for my code, but the Acid3 test gives it a 100/100. I've tested it on other browsers, and FF3.6/IE9/Opera11 are all giving object for both - so the issue is just with Chrome (didn't check with other browsers, specifically IE8).

Answer (score 0):

Could you use SVGweb?  Here's [an example](http://codinginparadise.org/projects/svgweb/samples/javascript-samples/svg_object.html?svg.render.forceflash=false) of using an 'object' tag. I'm by no means an SVGweb guy, but I'm looking at the example in Chrome inspector and I can see `<g>` nodes just fine.  (Plus you'd have IE support built in.)

It is another dependency, though (and they also rely on conditional comments for IE, not sure if that is acceptable in your situation).

Alternatively, you could [cheat off their source code](http://codinginparadise.org/projects/svgweb/src/svg-uncompressed.js) and see how they do it.  (Holy crap, they put tomes of documentation in there!)