# Acces SVG file included in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I included a SVG file in my HTML document with `<embed src="mySvg.svg" />` and now I want to manipulate what is inside my SVG.

I found that the SVG is not in "document" but in "window".

In my SVG file, I have a script :
(the init function in launch onload)
`function init(evt) {

    svgDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
svgDocument.getElementById('anIdOfMySvgFile'); // I successfully get the element of the SVG file

this.parent.document.getElementById('anIdOfMyHtmlFile'); // I successfully get the element of the HTML file

}`

But how can I select an element from my SVG file with a script located in my HTML file ?
window.document is my HTML file ... but I don't know how my SVG file is identified !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the content of the "embed" tag in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496241/how-to-access-the-content-of-the-embed-tag-in-html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set an ID on the `embed`, then use `document.getElementById` to grab it. Make sure to access the SVG through `getSVGDocument()`.

```
<embed src="mySvg.svg" id="mySvg" />

<script type="text/javascript">
        var mySvg = document.getElementById("mySvg");
        mySvg.addEventListener("load", function() {
            var svg = mySvg.getSVGDocument();
            svg.getElementById("[insert svg element id here]");
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it, I get an error : svg is undefined ... So myScv has no "contentDocument" child.

Comment: Yeh ! That works ! In my SVG file, I have tried alert(svgDocument) and I got [Object SVGDocument], but I had no idea there was a getSVGDocument function.