# Animate embed svg css + js

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, embed

I have made some paths in Illustrator and exported this as .svg. Now I want to animate these paths with css and javascript. I have already found a good fiddle that is working when I load the svg inline in HTML5. Because there are many paths(about 500) I want to embed this in HTML5. My problem: I can't access the svg file while it's embedded. How can I access all my paths/lines/polygons while the svg is embedded?

**HTML:**

```
<embed src="pano_botanique.svg" width="100%" height="100%" ; type="image/svg+xml"      id='svgsource' />
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var svgs = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');

    function selfdraw() {
        for (var i = 0; i < svgs.length; i++) {
            svgs[i].classList.add('draw');
        }
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
svg * {
    fill: none;
    stroke: none;
}

.draw * {
    stroke: #3675D8;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
    -webkit-animation: self-draw 30s ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes self-draw {
    0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 100%
    }
    40% {
    stroke-dasharray: 100% 0%
    } 
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
var svgs = document.getElementById('svgsource').contentDocument();
svgs.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var svg = svgs.contentDocument();

function selfdraw() {
    for (var i = 0; i < svgs.length; i++) {
        svgs[i].classList.add('draw');
    }
}
});
```

This should work but doesn't :(

Answer (score 0):

You can put the stylesheet in a <style> element inside the svg file.

Note that by using <embed> the svg nodes are in a different document. That means that for `getElementsByTagName(...)` to work you need to call it on the svg document, not on the main document.

But simply replacing `document` with e.g `document.getElementById('svgsource').getSVGDocument()` isn't guaranteed to work unless you wait for the svg document to finish loading (read: you can't do this from `$(document).ready`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3510578/109374) for more details.

Also see [How to access the content of the "embed" tag in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496241/how-to-access-the-content-of-the-embed-tag-in-html).