# Any way to add a class to embedded SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm building a site that has an embedded SVG logo at the top.  It has a nifty animation as it draws itself.  Though in tests, the animation is distracting as it animates on every page. I added a class to the SVG where if it has

```
 <svg class="showAnimation">
```

it animates, and if it doesn't have that class, it doesn't animate.  Or even if the showAnimation class is on any parent, that will work.  But doing

```
<embed src="/media/logo.svg" class="showAnimation">
```

doesn't work as I guess classes in the HTML aren't propagated down.  I don't want to inline the SVG file and have the whole thing re-loaded on every page.

The long story short is: I'm looking for an efficient way to add/remove classes to an embedded SVG from the HTML/CSS/Javascript side before the SVG is shown.  Inline is inefficient as it can't be cached, making two separate SVG files with only one word different is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the elements inside an `embed` element through `getSVGDocument()`.

```
var el = document.getElementById("embed's-id");
el.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var svg = el.getSVGDocument().getElementById("your-svg's-id");
  svg.setAttribute('class', 'showAnimation');
});
```

If the `load` event doesn't trigger, try doing it this way.

```
function checkIfLoaded() {
  var svg = document.getElementById("embed's-id").getSVGDocument();
  if (svg == null) {
    setTimeout(checkIfLoaded, 100);
  } else {
    svg.setAttribute('class', 'showAnimation');
  }
}

checkIfLoaded();
```

Comment: Any idea why "load" may never trigger?  Nothing in that function is run.  There are no javascript errors, I do var embedLogo = document.getElementById("embedLogo");
embedLogo.addEventListener("load", function() { alert("loaded");}); and never get an alert.  From the javascript console I can check that embedLogo is defined properly though.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed - Strange! It should work. Maybe try doing it [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/59q9nfxz/1/).

Comment: Hmm, this is unrelated to my last problem… but it looks like classList doesn't work on an SVGDocument.  document.getElementById("embedLogo").classList works fine.  document.getElementById("embedLogo").getSVGDocument().classList returns undefined.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed - Opps my bad! You have to do `svg.setAttribute('class', 'showAnimation')` instead.

Comment: .setAttribute is also undefined for the SVGDocument (again working only on the HTML element).

Comment: `getSVGDocument` may not work in all situations.  Try using the `getSubDocument()` function from the script linked to in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496241/how-to-access-the-content-of-the-embed-tag-in-html/8496279#8496279