# Include SVG files with HTML, and still be able to apply styles to them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

You can include SVG files into your HTML file via `embed` `object` and `svg` tags.

- Using an `embed` or `object` tag requires linking the image with a URL. (This is what I prefer, because I don't like all that SVG code in my HTML code, so I’d like to keep it that way.)
- Using the `svg` tag (AFAIK) requires having the SVG code inline in your HTML code.

## My question is:

*How do I include SVG icons, images, and other files into my HTML file, without having to put the entire SVG code in, and still be able to apply styles to them? Applying them through JS is fine too.*

### Note:

When I include them via `object` or `embed`, I can't seem to access them through jQuery, even with `$("#my-svg-div").find("svg")` (which, by the way, almost every answer on SO says I should). I just get `undefined`.

Thank you!

Comment: Basically...you can't...easily that is - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906148/how-to-apply-a-style-to-an-embedded-svg?rq=1

Comment: Okay.. So I'm assuming that being able to access the dashArrayOffset of an SVG, means I would be able to access the style as well. I have an object tag and this plugin is able to draw the stroke of the SVG even though it's an object and not an SVG. https://github.com/maxwellito/vivus I'm looking at the code now... Can't see anything useful

Comment: Well `dashArrayOffset` is a CSS property so, unless it's embedded in the SVG itself, then yes. ...but you'd have to test it.

Answer (score 36):

## Short Answer

You can programmatically inline an SVG image. Such an image can be treated essentially identically to an actual inline `<svg>` element, including being able to have styles applied to it.

If your SVG image is referenced in an `<object>` or `<iframe>` element (`e`), you can inline it as follows:

`e.parentElement.replaceChild(e.contentDocument.documentElement.cloneNode(true), e);`

If your SVG image is referenced in an `<embed>` element, replace `.contentDocument` in the above code with `.getSVGDocument()`.

If your SVG image is referenced in an `<img>` element, a completely different strategy, involving AJAX and described below, can be used to inline the image.

## General Strategy

If your external SVG image files are same-origin (e.g. the images are loaded from the same place as the HTML code), then one approach that allows styling of these images is to programmatically inline them as follows:

- Retrieve the content of the external SVG file.
- Add that content directly back to your HTML file in the same HTML DOM location as the original referencing element, i.e. put it "in-line".
- Delete the element that originally referenced the external SVG file.

## Benefits

This inlining strategy gives you the best of two worlds:

1. You get the benefits of separate image files, including:

   - organizing your image files independently of the HTML,
   - keeping your original HTML file uncluttered from image details, and
   - (potentially) allowing the browser to cache the images (but see below regarding this last point).
2. Yet you can still do anything to the eventually-inlined SVG images that you could do to `<svg>` elements that were truly originally inline, including:

   - applying CSS stylings to them,
   - applying event listeners to individual SVG shapes or groups, etc.

## Implementation

### For `<object>` or `<iframe>` elements:

You can inline externally referenced SVG code as follows:

```
// using vanilla JavaScript (as shown above):
e.parentElement.replaceChild(e.contentDocument.documentElement.cloneNode(true), e);

// using jQuery:
$e.replaceWith($($e[0].contentDocument.documentElement).clone());
```

...where `e` or `$e` are the vanilla or jQuery variables (respectively) in which you have selected an external-SVG-referencing `<object>` or `<iframe>` element.

### To include `<embed>` elements:

If, instead, you are using an external-SVG-referencing `<embed>` element, then you can inline the SVG content by replacing `.contentDocument` in the above code with `.getSVGDocument()` (note the additional parentheses). Note that `.contentDocument` does not work with `<embed>` elements while `.getSVGDocument()` actually works with all three element types. However `.getSVGDocument()` [is deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#InterfaceGetSVGDocument) and so should only be used if you really need `<embed>` elements.

### To include `<img>` elements:

Neither of the above strategies works for `<img>` elements. To inline these, you can retrieve the `src` attribute of the `<img>` element, make an AJAX request for that file, create a new `<svg>` element using the retrieved SVG code and replace the original `<img>` element with the new `<svg>` element. If you want this strategy to work for all four element types, then just be aware that the URL of the referenced SVG image is held in the `src` attribute of `<iframe>`, `<embed>` and `<img>` elements but in the `data` attribute of an `<object>` element. This strategy can be implemented as follows:

```
// using vanilla JavaScript:
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", e.getAttribute(e.nodeName === "OBJECT" ? "data" : "src");
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
    e.outerHTML = xhr.responseText;
  }
};

// using jQuery:
$.get($e.attr($e.prop("nodeName") === "OBJECT" ? "data" : "src"), function(data) {
  $e.replaceWith(data.documentElement);
});
```

## Example

The following example demonstrates where the above strategy does and does not allow external CSS stylings to be applied to originally-external SVG images. *(I didn't create a code snippet or jsfiddle because of the need to reference local external files.)*

The following two screenshots show the CSS styling (red triangles) or lack thereof (black triangles) before and after inlining. It shows the results for SVG images originally embedded in the HTML (`<svg>`) or referenced in the indicated elements (`<object>`, `<iframe>`, `<embed>`, and `<img>`). The three rows show the results of inlining using the three indicated strategies.

Before clicking the button, no inlining has yet been attempted, and the screen looks like this. Only embedded SVG elements (the 1st column) are styled:

[image: svg polygon styling by CSS before svg inlining]

After clicking the button, inlining is attempted, and the screen now looks like this. CSS styling has been successfully applied to some of the elements:

[image: svg polygon styling by CSS after svg inlining]

The code required for this example follows:

**`image.svg`** (externally referenced file, i.e. not embedded in the HTML):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50px" height="50px">
  <polygon points="25,5 45,45 5,45 25,5"/>
</svg>
```

**`index.html`** (obviously, remove the jQuery script line if not using jQuery):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <button>Click to attempt to inline svg images.</button>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>svg   </th>
      <th>object</th>
      <th>iframe</th>
      <th>embed </th>
      <th>img   </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>contentDocument</td>
      <td><svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50"><polygon points="25,5 45,45 5,45 25,5"/></svg></td>
      <td><object data="image.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></td>
      <td><iframe  src="image.svg" width="50" height="50" style="border: none;"></iframe></td>
      <td><embed   src="image.svg" type="image/svg+xml" /></td>
      <td><img     src="image.svg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>getSVGDocument()<br />(deprecated)</td>
      <td><svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50"><polygon points="25,5 45,45 5,45 25,5"/></svg></td>
      <td><object data="image.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></td>
      <td><iframe  src="image.svg" width="50" height="50" style="border: none;"></iframe></td>
      <td><embed   src="image.svg" type="image/svg+xml" /></td>
      <td><img     src="image.svg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>XMLHttpRequest</td>
      <td><svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50"><polygon points="25,5 45,45 5,45 25,5"/></svg></td>
      <td><object data="image.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></td>
      <td><iframe  src="image.svg" width="50" height="50" style="border: none;"></iframe></td>
      <td><embed   src="image.svg" type="image/svg+xml" /></td>
      <td><img     src="image.svg" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**`styles.css`** (only the `polygon` line is important for demonstrating the inlining):

```
polygon {fill: red;}
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
td, th {border: solid black 1px; padding: 0.4em;}
```

**`main.js`** (jQuery version):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    ["object", "iframe", "embed", "img"].forEach(function(elmtType) {
      var $e, $threeElmts = $(elmtType);
      $e = $($threeElmts[0]);
      if ($e[0].contentDocument) $e.replaceWith($($e[0].contentDocument.documentElement).clone());
      $e = $($threeElmts[1]);
      if ($e[0].getSVGDocument) $e.replaceWith($($e[0].getSVGDocument().documentElement).clone());
      $e = $($threeElmts[2]);
      $.get($e.attr($e.prop("nodeName") === "OBJECT" ? "data" : "src"), function(data) {
        $e.replaceWith(data.documentElement);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

**`main.js`** (vanilla JavaScript version):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    ["object", "iframe", "embed", "img"].forEach(function(elmtType) {
      var e, threeElmts = document.querySelectorAll(elmtType);
      e = threeElmts[0];
      if (e.contentDocument) e.parentElement.replaceChild(e.contentDocument.documentElement.cloneNode(true), e);
      e = threeElmts[1];
      if (e.getSVGDocument) e.parentElement.replaceChild(e.getSVGDocument().documentElement.cloneNode(true), e);
      e = threeElmts[2];
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET", e.getAttribute(e.nodeName === "OBJECT" ? "data" : "src"));
      xhr.send();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) e.outerHTML = xhr.responseText;
      };
    });
  });
});
```

### Note the following:

- This strategy will require you to deal with any characteristics associated with the original referencing elements, e.g. fallback images, `id` and `class` (or any other) attributes, event listeners, `iframe` functionality, etc.
- Ensure that you only attempt inlining after the image file has actually been loaded.
- Consider inlining on the server-side to allow serving of a single file, but inlining on the client-side to allow image file caching.
- I verified this strategy in Firefox 44.0, Chrome 49.0 and Opera 35.0 (Mac and Windows), Safari 9.0 (Mac) and IE 11 (Windows). I did not check Edge or any mobile browsers.
- This solution addresses referencing SVG files from `object`, `iframe`, `embed`, and `img` elements. It does not address external SVG images referenced in CSS `background-image` properties or in the `drawImage` function of a `<canvas>` context. I suspect those won't work this way, but I haven't checked.
- If you are attempting to duplicate the example code on your local computer by copying and saving the code and then "open"ing `index.html`, Chrome and Opera have security settings that will make this impossible. To get those browsers to work in such a local configuration, you instead need to run a local server as instructed in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33801287/5218951). There should be no such problem if you are using the inlining strategy in a normal server-hosted web site.

Comment: very interesting , I may be adding Codepens of my own discoveries over the next few days.

Comment: Holy shit. You OWNED this answer. I hope it gets the attention it deserves. Nice work.

Comment: Thanks @tayvano for the compliment. I (hopefully) just made the answer even better by including an alternative strategy (using AJAX) to allow inlining of <img> elements in addition to <object>, <iframe> or <embed> elements.

Comment: This is an ideal answer for external SVG resources. Loading the SVG contents async then injecting them as SVG code in the DOM is much more practical.

Answer (score 3):

This is the most comprehensive walkthrough of (1) the different ways of using SVGs in your HTML and (2) what styling the individual pieces (ie: paths) of the SVG via CSS/JS you can do.

https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

1. In an image tag (ie: `<img src="picture.svg" />` or as a background image in CSS = no styling
2. Inline - style away, but it'll clutter your HTML. PHP helps here, or you could use a gulp build task or something to keep the SVGs from cluttering your working code, while still being inline in the end.
3. As an object you can now add CSS **within** the .svg file:

   ```
   <svg ...>
     <style>
       /* SVG specific fancy CSS styling here */
     </style>
     ...
   </svg>
   ```

   or

   ```
   <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="svg.css" ?>
   ```
4. Data URIs - can be great for background images. No styling.

Comment: You can also inject dynamic CSS into the SVG with an object tag using javascript.

Comment: Really? Can you throw a codepen together demonstrating. I would be really interested in playing with this.