# How to reference SVGs in html with access to css styling

Tags: svg

I have a number of different SVGs to include in my project (Angular 10).
Some of them are used multiple times with different sizes and fill colors etc.

I am trying to find a way to reference them in my html code and have access to via styling:

**CSS:**

```
.svg {
  fill: red;
}
```

**Referencing:**

```
<svg>
   <use></use>
</svg>
```

```
<object></object>
```

```
<img></img>
```

```
<embed></embed>
```

As yet, I have not been able to find a solution that allows me to reference them but also have the ability to access the fill property in the SVG itself as i can when adding inline.

**Inline:**

```
<svg>
   <path>
   </path>
</svg>
```

Adding them inline is going to be messy.

How is this usually handled?

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: There are plenty of questions on this already. Why don't they meet your needs?

Comment: Hey Robert, I wasn't able to figure out how to achieve this from the questions I looked though. Including the svg was not a problem, but I couldn't style them with the projects css.

Comment: which questions did you look at and why didn't they work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  CSS does not apply across document boundaries.  If the CSS rules are in the HTML (or imported into the HTML via `<link>`) then it cannot affect the content of external files.

One solution people have used in the past is to [use a bit of Javascript to inline SVG files at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783441/include-svg-files-with-html-and-still-be-able-to-apply-styles-to-them).

Otherwise, you will need to put the CSS in the external SVG itself.