# How to get the document of an embedded website with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Im trying around with HTML and found the -tag.
I provided an url as src and the website does load without problems.
However I canot get the HTML-Code of this inner website. How can I access it with JS?

I already tried

```
innerHTML, children, childNodes
```

etc.

HTML

```
<div class="Webframe">
            <embed id="webframe" src="http://testapp.galenframework.com/"></embed> 
</div>
```

Console output of

```
let webframe = document.getElementById("webframe");
console.log(webframe)
```

can be seen here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFFUP.jpg

If anyone has an idea how to access this #document, I would be happy to try it out

Thank you in advance

Comment: My guess is to wait for the embed to load on the page, then dig down to what you need using a query selector

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8496279/1971378 might help.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is the lack of interface to do your task with `<embed>`. Better to use `<iframe>`.

The second is to try to access content from another domain without CORS. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Lets try a local page in a `<iframe>`. Now you can access the iframe`s`contentDocument`:

```html
<iframe id="webframe" src="test2.html"></iframe> 

<script>
let webframe = document.getElementById("webframe");
webframe.onload = ()=> console.log(webframe.contentDocument.body.outerHTML);
</script>
```

If you have access to another domain server, you can add "`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`" to the HTTP header and try it.

Comment: I forgot to say: You must wait for `webframe.onload` event to get the wanted document.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <div class="Webframe">
     <embed id="webframe" src="http://testapp.galenframework.com/" /> 
   </div>
   let webframe = document.getElementById("webframe");
   console.log(webframe)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that most modern browsers have deprecated and removed support for browser plug-ins, so relying upon <embed> is generally not wise if you want your site to be operable on the average user's browser.

Comment: i use it in electron, can this get a probelm in the fututre?