# base href + SVG Sprites = Not working on Firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, svg, grunt-svgstore

I'm using a technique I found on CSS Tricks ( https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/ ) to include my SVG sprite in my application.

It's a basic AngularJS application, I include the SVG and then I use the  tag to implement the icons.

```
<svg class="svg-icon"><use class="icon" xlink:href="#svgSprite-iconName" /></svg>
```

All of this works fine in all the browsers except Firefox. After investigating, I noticed it's my base href (that I cannot remove because of the way the application is plugged into an older system) that's causing the issue:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this problem?

Comment: You'll have to use absolute URLs if you can't remove `<base>`. Of course that will break things on most other UAs. So if you can't remove `<base>` life is going to be pretty hard for you.

Comment: The only other way would be to move all the SVG code into a separate file and display it via the `<object>` or `<iframe>` tag, rewriting any javascript as necessary for the new structure.

Comment: What if I need to modify the colors? I'm thinking embedding it in an object won't make it editable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753732/how-to-access-svg-elements-with-javascript or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911525/is-it-possible-to-navigate-svg-objects-elements-from-enclosing-html

Comment: I think, this could be resolve your problem [Stackoverflow --> SVG symbols not being displayed in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306759/svg-symbols-not-being-displayed-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty much like a hack, but here's my **ugly** solution:

If you're using **ngRoute**:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
    $rootScope.locationOrigin = $location.absUrl // Don't forget to inject `$location` dependency
});
```

or **UI-Router**:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
    $rootScope.locationOrigin = $location.absUrl // Don't forget to inject `$location` dependency
});
```

And in your **index.html**:

```
<base href="/" 
      ng-href="{{locationOrigin()}}" />
```